# How to calculate the time between an event in the past and today in Power Query

Tags: powerquery

What I try to do seems so trivial, but I just can't figure it out, even not with the help of Google.
I just want to know the time in days that has elapsed between a candidate applying for a job, and today. In plain Excel it would be =Now()-[Date Applied], What would it be in Power **Query**? Not Power BI, not Power Pivot, not DAX

Thanks a million.
Carl

Answer (score 1):

Found it eventually
Select the time/date column (by clicking the column header).
Click Transform -->Date-->Age
Click Transform-->Duration-->Day
These two transform operations will change the selected column to the duration.